# Parsing indentation with FastParse

Tags: java, scala, parsing, fastparse

I'm trying to parse an indented language using FastParse and I'm struggling finding any resources or information on it.
There is only one example I can find [here](https://www.lihaoyi.com/fastparse/#GettingStarted) that shows how to parse and calculate the sum of the integers in the tree structure. I've tried copying this code but I get the same error where it fails parsing `\n`.

I would like to parse this.

```
example
  1
  2
  3
```

Code

```
import fastparse.all._

class ExampleParser(indent: Int) {

  val word: P[String] = P("example".!)

  val number: P[String] = P( CharIn('0'to'9').rep(1).! )

  val blockBody: P[Seq[String]] = "\n" ~ deeper.flatMap(i => new ExampleParser(indent = i).number.rep(1, sep = ("\n" + " " * i).~/))

  val deeper: P[Int] = P(" ".rep(indent + 1).!.map(_.length))

  val section: P[(String, Seq[String])] = P(word ~ blockBody)

  val expr: P[(String, Seq[String])] = P(section)

}

object Main
{
  def main(args: Array[String]) =
  {
    check(
      """example
        |  1
        |  2
        |  3
      """.stripMargin.trim

    )
    println()
  }

  def check(str: String) = {
    new ExampleParser(0).expr.parse(str) match {
      case Parsed.Success(value, _) => println(value)
      case Parsed.Failure(a, b, c) => println("Failure:" + a + ":" + b + ":" + c)
    }
  }
}
```

Output

```
Failure:"\n":7:Extra(...ample
1
2
3, [traced - not evaluated])
```

How can I parse this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If I change "expression" to "example":

```
check (
  """example
    |  1
    |  2
    |  3
  """.stripMargin.trim
)
```

I get the result:

```
[info] Running Main 
(example,ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3))
```

Of course you might like to change it the other way round.

Comment: I believe I mistyped when adding the question. I originally was testing it with the parser expecting `expression` but changed it to `example` for this. 
I'll be able to test this soon thank you.

Comment: I've changed this and it produces the same error. 
I've copied the code I have in the example into a new class called `ExampleParser`. I've updated `expression` to be `example` too. When running this I get `Failure:"\n":7:Extra(...ample
  1
  2
  3, [traced - not evaluated])`
This is with `fastparse_2.12`.

Comment: I have a feeling this might be dependant on the operating system used as creating the string could be spaced with `\r\n` on Windows.
When running with `example\n 1\n 2` I get a null pointer exception.

Comment: I used Linux, scala-2.12 and sbt.